# Create and display table column hierarchy in Tableau

Tags: structure, tableau-api, hierarchy, hierarchical-clustering

My table currently has a number of similar numerical columns I'd like to nest under a common label.

My current table is something like:

```
| Week | Seller count, total | Seller count, churned | Seller count, resurrected |
| ---- | ------------------- | --------------------- | ------------------------- |
|   1  |         100         |           10          |              4            |
|   2  |         105         |           12          |              5            |
```

And I'd like it to be:

```
|      |       Seller count            |
| Week | Total | Churned | Resurrected |
| ---- | ----- | ------- | ----------- |
|   1  |  100  |   10    |      4      |
|   2  |  105  |   12    |      5      |
```

I've seen examples of this, including a related instructional [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BkUD5gPP6-4), but this video hides the actual creation of the nested object (called "Segment").

I also tried creating a hierarchy by [dragging](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/qs_hierarchies.htm) items in the "Data" tab on top of one another. This function appears to only be possible for dimensions (categorical data), not measures (numerical data) like mine.

Even so, I can drag my column names from the measures side onto the dimensions side to get them to be considered dimensions. Then I can drag to nest and create the hierarchy. But then when I drag the top item of the hierarchy ("Seller count" in the example below) into the "Columns" field, I get the warning "the field being added contains 92,000 members, and maximum recommended is 1,000". It thinks this is categorical data, and is maybe planning to create a subheading for each value (100, 105, etc.), instead of the desired hierarchy sub-items as subheadings.

Any idea how to accomplish this simple hierarchical restructuring of my column labels?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is some data restructuring and Tableau isn't best suited for it.  Still, it is simple one and you can do it like this-

- I recreated one table like yours in excel, and imported it in Tableau

[image]

[image]

- Rename the three cols, (removed `seller count` from their names)

[image]

- selected these three columns at once, and select pivot to transform these like

[image]

- Rename these columns again

[image]

- create a text table in tableau, as you have shown in question

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This looks like exactly what I'm hoping to do. Unfortunately, for some reason, I'm not seeing the "Pivot" option when I select the 3 columns and right click. I'm seeing these options: Rename, Reset names, Copy values, Hide (greyed out), Create calculated field..., and Merge mismatched fields. It seems like other people have had this issue, and maybe solved it by making a [copy](https://community.tableau.com/s/question/0D54T00000C6Ac5SAF/cant-see-a-pivot-option-on-the-data-grid) of the data. I'm not able to -- I've got ca. 10M rows -- seeing "Limit cannot exceed threshold 100000".